# Draw from negative binomial 2 in R

Tags: r, bayesian, stan

Is there a way to draw random numbers in R from a negative binomial distribution with alternative parametrisation (mu, phi), the equivalent of neg_binomial_2_rng.

https://mc-stan.org/docs/functions-reference/nbalt.html

Comment: See [rnbinom](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/stats/html/NegBinomial.html) function, read the details for the alternative specification. You need to specify ``mu`` for $\mu$ and ``size`` for $\phi$

Answer (score 0):

Yes use rnbinom(n.samples, mu=mu, size=phi)